# Split Bootstrap Carousel in two part

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How can I split Bootstrap Carousel in two part and connect them?
I'm trying to get something like Prezi's carousel ([www.prezi.com](http://www.prezi.com) - it is at the bottom of the page: #p-case-studies-section), which is split in two part, and images on the right one are connected with items in the first one.

Comment: I can't see a carousel on prezi.com. Can you show us what you have attempted? Maybe make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with two carousels and explain what you want to hallen with them?

Comment: It is at the bottom of the page: #p-case-studies-section

Comment: I've searched the source of that page and can't find a `#p-case-studies-section` element, maybe I'm being served a different version of that page.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use the 'data-slide-to' attribute on your clickable images. If you look at this example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

..you see data-slide-to used on the carousel indicators (circles on top of the carousel images). To make it work like prezi.com, just apply data-slide-to attribute to images located outside of the carousel, for example in a div to the right of the carousel.

You are not necessarily splitting the carousel in two, but moving the indicator icons to another part of the page.

Comment: If I put .carousel-indicators out of Carousel container, class "active" doesn't work. I thing it is because now data-target is not properly linking with Carousel Container.

Comment: As an alternative approach, using $("#myImage").click(function(){
    $("#myCarousel").carousel(3);
});
may be a better method. Just put click events on your images that are outside the carousel and fire the .carousel(n) method. This seems to work for me when I tested it.